# Spreadsheet: store multiple entries for one "field" per row

Tags: spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that inventories our sheet music collection with multiple fields like title, composer, etc:

| Octavo # | Title - original language | Composer | Arranger | Editor | Poet | Translator | Voicing | Language | Accomp | Publisher | ID# | # | Mstrwrk | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 248 | Two Motets | Monteverdi |  | Arnold, Denis |  |  | SSATTB | Latin | basso continuo | Oxford University Press | ISBN 0 19 337583 4 | 48 | ("Adoramus Te" and "Cantate Domino") | Singular English Copy |

At the end of each row, I would like to store all the performance dates for the piece. Some pieces will inevitably have multiple dates. If I keep extending columns to the right, they won't be sortable. However, if I put all the dates for each piece in one cell, they won't be dynamically sortable inside that cell either and the rows will need to resize in ugly ways.

I want to:

- Easily see when each piece has been performed
- Sort in reverse chronological order to see most recent pieces
- Not lose the ability to sort chronologically (although I will rarely do it)

How would you suggest storing this information? We're currently using Google Sheets for easy sharing, but will eventually put it back in Excel, probably mostly used in Excel Online.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Either solution presented would not eliminate the possibility of dynamically sorting the content.  Also, row heights do not need to change with multi-line content.  Why don't you edit your question to explain what you want to be able to do (e.g. dynamically sort the content most recent or oldest date, or do you want to filter all sheet music based on a particular performance date? etc.)  Please also provide a sample of your data in markdown or share a spreadsheet.  Also indicate if this solution is in Google Sheets, Excel or something else.

Comment: Added info. 

If multiple dates are saved in one cell, won't it only sort based on the first date? I want to see all dates by eye so I would have to resize the row if it exceeds the width.

Comment: Spreadsheets were not originally intended to be used as databases. They might work great as database for simple data structures like a CSV.  Nowadays there are a large number or options to handle more complex data structures thatn simple tables without the hasle of a database management system. Why are you trying to use a spreadsheet for this?

Comment: The reason to ask you "why" is to understand if there are constrains. Without constrains (or some sort of criteria to determine what a good answer should include) this looks as a primarily opinion based question which are off-topic on this site. P.S. Askers should search and research before asking a question and share what they found explaining why that was not work for the case exposed to make the post helpful for everyone. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need two lists. One is the list you show, the other is simply the ID#'s and dates performed (each row would be one ID and one date). You could then create lookups and/or queries to display results to suit your needs.

I'm not as familiar with Google Sheets, but imagine there's equivalent functionality to Excel. To list all dates for a given ID, the excel formula would be (note [] designates the ranges with your data) `=textjoin(CHAR(10), true, filter([date listing], [ID column] = ID target))`.

Adding sample screenshot:
[image]

The "orange" table is your original list, and the "yellow" one is the listing of performances. You could also add a lookup of descriptions to the yellow table, if you like.

The formula in the orange table for Column1 is `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,TEXT(FILTER(Table2[Date],Table2[ID]=[@ID]),"m/d/yyyy"))`. You could use `SORT(FILTER(...))`, and you could add `TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER9...)))` to Column D (moving the yellow table, of course) to put each date in its own column (it would have to be outside the bounds of the table or you get SPILL errors).

2nd edit:
[image]

Comment: So, then I need to manually fill the second sheet with the ID numbers? That's difficult as we sometimes move things around.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by filling the second sheet. Each time a piece is performed, you'd add a row with its ID and the date. If you have 100 pieces, but only one is performed, your second list is one row with that one ID and one date. The next time a piece is performed, you'd have a second row with its ID and its date. The ID is/should be the unique identifier for a piece. If it changes, you can do a find/replace.